# Xamarin webview calling LoadFinished multiple times

Tags: xamarin, webview

Trying to simply just execute C# code after the webview has **COMPLETELY** finished. It seems common sense, but I can't find a reliable way to do this.

What I've tried so far:

In my platform level code, I have a WebViewRenderer, with a LoadFinished method that gets called via the webview.LoadFinished delegate.

```
    void LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int contentHeight = 0;

        string readyState = this.webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.readyState").ToString();
        App.ConsoleWriteLine($"ReadyState: {readyState}");
        ...
```

In my console, I see ReadyState: Interactive and ReadyState: Complete like 4-5 times. My goal here was to listen for the readyState to be complete, but it's hitting multiple times.

I think tried to insert javascript into my dom and wait for `window.onload` to fire. But this fires multiple times too!

`window.onload = function () { alert('here'); }`

"alert" is shown like 4-5 times.

Is there any reliable way either in javascript OR C# that I can know when exactly everything that I'm loading is finished?

Comment: I think when you read "document.readyState" you are causing the document to change which triggers those callbacks. If I am right you should be going to endless loop actually unless at some point the doc is not modified anymore. Just to test try to remove this  line: 
 this.webView.EvaluateJavascript

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that. Except, I put that in there because loadfinished also was geting fired multiple times. But this is interesting, I will give it a go, thanks.

Comment: No that is not the reason since I don't read that anymore and it still fired multiple times :(

Comment: It is iOS correct? Unfortunately my MAC just died after installing Sierra so I will not be able to help :-(